# Vaadin 8 Spring Boot QuickTickets Dashboard with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin4spring

I'm trying to adapt Vaadin Spring Boot QuickTickets Dashboard example with my project needs. Everything is working fine except I'm unable to access another (not Vaadin UI) URLs. For example, I have Spring Boot Actuator endpoint - http://localhost:8080/actuator/health but when I try to access it, the application wrongly redirects me to http://localhost:8080/actuator/health#!dashboard. Pretty much the same behavior with my custom login page(not Vaadin UI) - http://localhost:8080/login. I also unable to access it.

How to correctly setup Vaadin to be able to access Spring Boot Actuator endpoints and my custom login page also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map the servlet to a different path. I think the problem is that the Vaadin-Servlet is mapped to / an is processing all requests.

Adding the following to you application.properties should do the trick.

```
vaadin.servlet.urlMapping = /myapp/*
```

Of course the URL of the app changes accordingly.